How can I split my dataframe so that consecutive numbers are each in their own dataframe?
I am new to using the python module pandas dataframes and i might have a silly question.
I have a large dataframe that is structured as follows:



index
ConsecutiveNumbers




idx1
1


idx2
2


idx3
3


idx4
4


idx5
1


idx6
2


idx7
3


and so on
and so on



How can i get this single dataframe into a list of multiple dataframes that each look like this:
df1:



index
ConsecutiveNumbers




idx1
1


idx2
2


idx3
3


idx4
4



df2:



index
ConsecutiveNumbers




idx5
1


idx6
2


idx7
3



and so on
The tricky part is that not every number series has the same length so the dataframe itself can not be splitted after every 120th row.
I tried to manually search for the beginning and end of the consecutive numbers series (with a for loop that iterrates rowwise through the dataframe). But that's not really fast and I feel like there has to be a better solution (maybe a slicing approach i am unaware of).
Since i am new to using dataframes, i lack of experience in this "more advanced" slicing approaches that search for a start and end of a consecutive series and get the inbetween as a new dataframe.

create dictionary of DataFrames by comapre difference of ConsecutiveNumbers column:
dfs = dict(iter(df.groupby((df['ConsecutiveNumbers'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()))))
print (dfs)
{1:        ConsecutiveNumbers
index                    
idx1                    1
idx2                    2
idx3                    3
idx4                    4, 2:        ConsecutiveNumbers
index                    
idx5                    1
idx6                    2
idx7                    3}

If need loop in dictionary:
for k, df in dfs.items():
    print (df)
       ConsecutiveNumbers
index                    
idx1                    1
idx2                    2
idx3                    3
idx4                    4
       ConsecutiveNumbers
index                    
idx5                    1
idx6                    2
idx7                    3

